# How to determine if a string is a number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the easiest way to find out in Rails 3 whether a string `str` contains a positive float number or not ? (`str` is not an attribute in an active-record model)

It should work like this:

```
str = "123"         =>     true
str = "123.456"     =>     true
str = "0"           =>     true
str = ""            =>     false
str = "abcd"        =>     false
str = "-123"        =>     false
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034418/determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-float-value (for Floats) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282273/does-ruby-1-9-2-have-an-is-a-function/4282299 (For Integers) . BTW, `123` isn't a Float, it's an Integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
class String
  def nonnegative_float?
    Float(self) >= 0
  rescue ArgumentError
    return false
  end
end
```

However, since you already seem to have a pretty good idea of what a nonnegative float number looks like, you could also match it against a `Regexp`:

```
class String
  def nonnegative_float?
    !!match(/\A\+?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\Z/)
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this disallows `.123`; while this is invalid as a Ruby literal float, I suspect this may commonly occur in user input.

Comment: @Phrogz: Unfortunately, the OP's requirements specification is *incredibly* vague and his test coverage isn't exactly great, either, so it's basically guesswork. You assume that `'.123'` is valid, even though there is no test case for it. I assume that `'+123'` is valid and `'  123  '` is not, even though there are no test cases for it. A better answer would basically require a better question.

Answer (score 0):

You can match it against a regular expression.

```
str === /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: This regexp is overly broad, allowing both negative numbers as well as things like `u suck d00d`.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add the beginning and end anchors. Fixed now.