# string value checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to check if a variable's string value is a number string (e.g. '3.2', '1') or alphabet string (e.g. 'abc'), is there any easy way to do this in ruby or Rails 3 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a string is a number ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538643/how-to-determine-if-a-string-is-a-number)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use Float().

```
def numeric?(object)
  true if Float(object) rescue false
end
```

Comment: I didn't know about that. Is `Float()` a class method defined on `Float`? It does not look like it is.

Comment: This is instantiating a new instance of the Float() class. It returns true on success and false on failure.

Comment: @sawa Ruby allows you to define a constant/module/class with the same name as a method. It's weird, but it allows the above. Try: `class Foo; end; def Foo; 42; end; p Foo.new, Foo, Foo()` Like `super`, it's one of the few cases where including or omitting parentheses on a no-argument method call makes a difference.

Comment: Actually, the `Kernel#Float` method returns the float object on success and **raises an error on failure**, so **you do not want this**. I am surprised that it has received so many upvotes.

Comment: @Rein It was originally written to handle the error raised by `Float()`, but somebody (I'm looking at you, [@Yule](http://stackoverflow.com/users/671422/yule)) edited it to use `!!Float` for "Slightly better readability" and completely broke it in the process. Rolled back to the functional version.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `is_numeric?` method to the string class:

```
class String
  def is_numeric?
    true if Float(self) rescue false
  end
end

p "123".is_numeric? # true
p "abc".is_numeric? # false
```

Using `Float()` instead of a regular expression handles some weird cases that you might not want to consider "numeric", like `+123` or `-.3`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions to help you with this.

```
str = "abc"
# first regex checks for character string, second regex checks for floating point number
if not str.empty? and str =~ /^[a-z]+$/i or str =~ /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/ then
  # this is a match
else
  # no match
end
```

I didn't fully test these regexes - you'd have to make sure these fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations using `Kernel#Float` expect and rescue an exception, which is slow and poor design. I would prefer:

```
class String
  def is_numeric?  
    string.to_f.to_s == string ||
      string.to_i.to_s == string
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. It won't work for many edge cases such as ".1" and "+12" or "012", all of which are valid floats. `Float` really is the better method.

Comment: Based on the inputs given, this is the better solution. Just in time, not just in case.

Answer (score -2):

```
string == /\d+\.?\d+/ ? "Numbers" : "Letters"
```

Comment: This doesn't account for negative numbers.

Comment: .123 isn't valid in Ruby 1.9.2 ;)

Comment: @jxpx Whether Ruby's parser will accept it has very little to do with whether OP's website should accept it as numeric input