# How to convert only strings hash values that are numbers to integers

Tags: ruby, string, integer, type-conversion

I have rows of hashes imported from several different XML database dumps that look like this (but with varying keys):

```
{"Id"=>"1", "Name"=>"Cat", "Description"=>"Feline", "Count"=>"123"}
```

I tried using `#to_i` but it converts a non-number string to `0`:

```
"Feline".to_i
# => 0
```

But what I'd like is a way for `"Feline"` to remain a string, while `Id` and `Count` in the above example become integers `1` and `123`.

Is there an easy way to convert *only* the strings values that are numbers into integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [Kernel#Integer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer):

```
my_hash = {"Id"=>"1", "Name"=>"Cat", "Description"=>"Feline", "Count"=>"123"}
Hash[ my_hash.map{ |a, b| [ a,
                            begin
                              Integer b
                            rescue ArgumentError
                              b
                            end ] } ]
```

ADDED LATER: With my `y_support` gem, you can make hash operations even more concise.

```
require 'y_support/core_ext/hash'
my_hash.with_values { |v| begin
                            Integer b
                          rescue ArgumentError
                            b
                          end }
```

`YSupport` can be installed by `gem install y_support` and also offers `Hash#with_keys`, `Hash#with_values!`, `Hash#with_keys!` that do what you expect they do, and `Hash#modify` that expects a binary block returning a pair of values, modifying the hash in place. There have been proposals to add such methods directly to the Ruby core in the future.

Comment: That intrigues me. Can you be more specific?

Comment: +1. Nice, thanks Boris. I like Brad's regex & ternary, though this is faster.

Comment: Proposal: `my_hash.each_pair { | k, v | my_hash[k] = Integer(v) rescue v }`

Comment: Not only that, this also avoids the need to parse the integer by yourself. Imagine you'd want to convert to Floats, where the strings can be like "-3.4e-19".

Comment: @undur_gongor: Thanks. I thought you hate my grouping of parethesis. I try to avoid just using trailing rescue, because it does not allow you to specify which error to rescue, but in this case, I think it's OK. Also, I generally avoid mentioning the name of the collection itself inside the block, with which I iterate on it.

Comment: +1 Nice Undur. Write that as an answer and you get the Accept.

Comment: @dj.: The key is using `Integer` so Boris should be honored.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: Generally, I agree to both of your concerns. In this special case, I would accept it, though. And indeed I do dislike the clustered parentheses in your code.

Comment: @undur_gongor: I think that in Ruby, I'll forever have block-envy towards Python :)

Answer (score 10):

One line answer:
Using regex approach

```
h.merge(h) { |k, v| v.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) ? v.to_i : v }
```

Using Integer approach

```
h.merge(h) { |k, v| Integer(v) rescue v }
```

Comment: In my private library, I actually defined #do_with_values method on Hashes, so in my code, I'd just say h.do_with_values { |v| Integer v rescue v }.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I think your answer is enough and sufficient. Mine is just complement :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you know what fields should be integers (your consuming code probably depends on it), so I would recommend you convert the specific fields.

```
c = Hash[h.map { |k,v| [k, %w(Id Count).include?(k) ? Integer(v) : v ] }]
```

Comment: True, though I'm also lazy and a fan of data-driven logic, so that I can replicate the algorithm on other xml without having to worry about matching field names to data types. Mapping fields to data types hard-codes the schema in my algorithm which I want to avoid, and also introduces further points of error and fat fingers. DNRY.

Answer (score 1):

I had a **similar** problem to solve, where results for pesticide analysis came into the system as a heterogeneous (bad design!) format... negative integers as special codes (not detected, not tested, not quantified etc...), `nil` as synonym as not detected, floats for quantified compounds and strings for pass/fail *boolean*... Hold your horses, this is a 10 years old-running in production, never *greenfield-ed* highly patched app ;)

**Two things** that I learned from top rubists:

`0) DON'T ITERATE-MODIFY AN ENUMERABLE (return a copy)`

`1) YOUR REGEX WON'T COVER ALL CASES`

While I am not a big fan of `rescue`, I think it fits the purpose of keeping the code clean. So, I've been using this to mitigate my input:

```
ha = { 
 "p_permethrin" => nil, 
 "p_acequinocyl"=>"0.124", 
 "p_captan"=>"2.12", 
 "p_cypermethrin"=>"-6", 
 "p_cyfluthrin"=>"-6",
 "p_fenhexamid"=>"-1", 
 "p_spinetoram"=>"-6", 
 "p_pentachloronitrobenzene"=>"-6", 
 "p_zpass"=>"true"
}

Hash[ha.map{|k,v| [k, (Float(v) rescue v)]}] # allows nil
Hash[ha.map{|k,v| [k, (Float(v) rescue v.to_s)]}] # nit to empty string
```

I would even

```
class Hash
  # return a copy of the hash, where values are evaluated as Integer and Float
  def evaluate_values
    Hash[self.map{|k,v| [k, (Float(v) rescue v)]}]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks *mekdigital* – I think there’s a lot to be said for pragmatism when trying to solve problems like this. Sometimes a sneaky `rescue` is exactly what’s needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex and the ternary operator, you could incorporate this into the logic somewhere:

```
string =~ /^\d+$/ ? string.to_i : string
```

Comment: While I think Boris' answer is more pure, I have a soft spot for regex and the ternary operator. I suspect Boris' begin/rescue would be faster though...

Comment: “Some people, when confronted with a problem, think ‘I know, I'll use regular expressions.’ Now they have two problems.” (Jamie Zawinski) What about `"-42"`? Your approach will convert `"abcd\n2\nefgh"` to `0`. Why not use `Integer()` which exists exactly for the given problem?

Answer (score 0):

This will handle not only integers but all numbers.

```
my_hash = {"Id"=>"1", "Name"=>"Cat", "Description"=>"Feline", "Count"=>"123"}

result = my_hash.inject({}) { |result,(key,value)|
    if value.match(/^\s*[+-]?((\d+_?)*\d+(\.(\d+_?)*\d+)?|\.(\d+_?)*\d+)(\s*|([eE][+-]?(\d+_?)*\d+)\s*)$/)
            result[key.to_sym] = value.to_i
    else
            result[key.to_sym] = value
    end
    result
}
```

Thanks to [Determine if a string is a valid float value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034418/determine-if-a-string-is-a-valid-float-value) for regexp

Comment: Uh oh, inject, a venerable keyword :). Where did you spork it?

Comment: Now, that's an overkill :) Unless you are paid by LOCs :)

Comment: Your regexp fails for multi-line strings. `my_hash = {"Id"=>"1", "Name"=>"Cat", "Description"=>"Feline\n42", "Count"=>"123"}` results in `{:Id=>1, :Name=>"Cat", :Description=>0, :Count=>123}`.

Answer (score -1):

Define a new method for String: **String#to_number**

```
class String
  def to_number
    Integer(self) rescue Float(self) rescue self
  end
end
```

Test it:

```
"1".to_number => 1
"Cat".to_number => "Cat"
```