# splitting an array into a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Im looking to split an array of strings and creating a hash out of it.

I have an algorithm that splits a string into an array by commas `this:1, is:1, a:1, string:1`

```
def split_answer_to_hash(str)
    words = str.split(',')
    answer = {}
     words.each do |w|
        a = w.split(':')
        h = Hash[ *a.collect { |v| [ v, a[1] ] } ]
        answer = h
    end
    answer
end
```

What I need to do now is to make the left side of the colon the key to the hash and the right side of the colon the value of the hash.  example: `{"this" =>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "string"=>1 }`

`*a.collect` is iterating through the array and making the value another key.  How can I go about this with out that happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is:

```
string = 'this:1, is:1, a:1, string:1'
hash = Hash[*string.split(/:|,/)]
#=> {"this"=>"1", " is"=>"1", " a"=>"1", " string"=>"1"}
```

Comment: @TonyShier - Obviously there are some downsides. What is to happen with string like `'hello:there:1,, or:2'`?

Comment: I can then use a solution I found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318021/how-to-convert-only-strings-hash-values-that-are-numbers-to-integers)

Comment: and further logic to the string I can just  edit out before going into the hash that you provided.  Basically its a word counter of sorts that I need to do math on.

Comment: Perhaps `/:|,\s+/` to remove the leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Having just one answer to this question just won't do:

```
str = "this:1, is:1, a:1, string:1"

Hash[str.scan(/(?:([^:]+):(\d+)(?:,\s)?)/)]
  .tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].to_i } }
  #=> {"this"=>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "string"=>1}
```

[Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) is used merely to convert the values from strings to integers. If you'd prefer:

```
h = Hash[str.scan(/(?:([^:]+):(\d+)(?:,\s)?)/)]
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].to_i }
h
  #=> {"this"=>1, "is"=>1, "a"=>1, "string"=>1}
```

For Ruby 2.1, you can replace `Hash[arr]` with `arr.to_h`.