# Regex to check if a number decimal separator is consistent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, csv

I have a `CSV::Table` object that contains many columns. Each column is composed by a certain number of elements, which are strings that is supposed to contain a number.

It can be using both `"."` or `","` as a decimal separator and it can't have any **thousand separator**.

**Valid examples**

- "1023.12"
- "2341,34"
- "1245"
- "1.456" *- notice that it appears to be a thousand separator with no decimal cases, but in thtat case it should be interpreted as a decimal separator*
- "1,435" *- the same observation above*

**Invalid examples**

- "1,434.12"
- "1.455,19"
- "1.499e5" *- scientific notation*
- "a134" *- just to be sure that there are no characters in the string*

Also, I need to be sure that the decimal separator is consistent along all columns and rows; so I need to extract the decimal separator that is used (`","` or `"."`).

What regex can I use to check that validity of the string and extract the decimal separator to check consistency across the table?

Comment: Instead of checking for consistency, why not convert to a canonical form you can depend on?

Comment: Would you consider `.1234` valid?

Comment: @tadman actually this was the next step ;) Is it possible to acomplish that and bypass the question subject?

Comment: @Blazemonger I would not expect to receive this input, so no :)

Comment: Just to clarify: the reason for extracting the symbol is to validate the next item.  Row 1 could use `12.34` and the second row would be invalid if it tried to use `12,34`?

Comment: This is one of the reasons. The other one is that I need to store the original separator to consistently use it on data export.

Comment: [This is very much relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1072196/84631)

Comment: @Mischa can you join here?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27184/ruby-conceptual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose this would work:

```
/^\d*([.,]?)\d+$/
```

This will also allow numbers like `.1234`, which are valid even if they are unusual.

To prohibit such numbers, try adding another pair of parentheses:

```
/^\d+(([.,])\d+)?$/
```

(Note that now the second pair of parentheses, not the first, contains your decimal separator.)

Comment: I think scientific notation was in the *invalid* list.

Comment: This will fail fir the input "1"

Comment: @JoeFrambach True. We can change the first + to *, but that lets `.1234` through. But then, OP said he didn't expect to receive that.

Comment: I mean to change it to `/^\d+([.,]\d+)?$/`

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thanks, adding.

Comment: Don't you need to escape the '.'?

Comment: Not inside of brackets, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

```
matches = table.flat_map { |r| r.map { |c| /\A\d+(?:([.,])\d+)?\z/.match(c) } }
raise 'InvalidNumbers' if matches.any?(&:nil?)
decimals = matches.map{|m| m[1]}.reject(&:empty?).uniq
raise 'InconsistentDecimals' if decimals.size > 1
decimal_seperator = decimals.first || '.'
```

The regexp matches for valid numbers, capturing the optional decimal seperator in match[1].  Error if any match fails (not a number). Error if there's more than one kind of separator (inconsistent).  If there were no separators, assume '.' as default.